# Make the "how's the site doing?" proposal link a bit more prominent

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

I just noticed that all the Area 51 pages for proposals in public beta have a link that will give an evaluation of the site's progress, which is very helpful in deciding which sites need a little extra boost. I've been cruising Area 51 since the first sites went into beta and haven't noticed it. Could we make the link a little more prominent, either by bolding it or relocating it? Expanding it by default for the proposals that have it might also help.

(If everybody else already saw this and I'm just slow, I'll delete this :)

Comment: Call me slow, but I still can't see it :(

Comment: @Benjol see the answer I posted. Its now permanently gone and the information's always displayed, so the problem disappeared. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if any moderators actually read this, but it looks like the solution was just implemented. The menu is now expanded by default and the link doesn't even exist anymore.

Kudos to the awesome stackexchange team! ;)

Comment: Yes, implemented this morning :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey! Cool feature.

It does not stand out, though, does it? I had to hunt around a bit to find it even after I read this question.

The thing is, it is not needed for using the site, and conveys information that can only be of interest to people who have gotten down into the nitty-gritty of area51 mechanics. SO it is not necessary for *everyone* to discover it. It'd be nice if it was easier to find, but don't make a mess of the layout to accomplish that.

Comment: it may not be necessary for everyone, but it would be helpful for those visiting the beta pages, the only place it would actually affect. It would be nice if everyone who looked at a site beta to evaluate its progress 'discovered' it as its the just about the most pertinent info on the page. I'm not necessary asking for a layout change, just a font-size or color change. :)